# nodejs passport LogIn

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I set-up passport on nodejs with mongoose for allowing users to login and create new accounts. Create new account is working but the login part doesn't.

**users.js**

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('login', {
        'title': 'Login'
    });
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){done(null, user);});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    User.getUserById(id, function(err, user){
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done){
        User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(!user){
                console.log('Unknown User');
                return done(null, false,{message: 'Unknown User'});
            }
            User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
                if(err) throw err;
                if(isMatch){
                    return done(null, user);
                }else{
                    console.log('Invalid Password');
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
                }
            });
        });
     }
));

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect: '/',failureRedirect: '/users/register', failureFlash:'Invalid username or password'}), function(req,res){
    console.log('Authentication Successful');
    req.flash('success', 'You are logged in');
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

**../models/user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodeauth');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     username: {
         type: String,
         index: true
     },
     password: {
         type: String, required: true, bcrypt: true
     },
     email:{
         type: String
     },
     name:{
         type: String
     },
     profileimage:{
         type: String
     }
 });

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
     bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch){
         if(err) return callback(err);
         callback(null,isMatch);
     });
 }

 module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
     User.findById(id, callback);
 }

 module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
     var query = {username: username};
     User.findOne(query, callback);
 }

 module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
     bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, 10, function(err, hash){
         if(err) throw err;
         // Set hashed pw
         newUser.password = hash;
         // Create User
         newUser.save(callback);
     });
 }
```

If I create the new user than is working the data are uploading the MongoDB but if I try to Log In it just drop me to the /users/register page I do not have any error

Comment: Unrelated: how is the profile image a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is not doing anything because your login route is not calling anything... check the documentation on http://passportjs.org/docs to see how passport works.

In user.js you need something like

```
router.get('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', {
    'title': 'Login'
    });
  });
```

Then in a separate file you need to setup your authentication strategy, for example:

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Check this tutorial for a step-by-step on implementing local authentication strategy.
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authenticating-nodejs-applications-with-passport--cms-21619

If you want something more advanced, this code has examples of social authentication strategies (for example, your users can log in using Facebook accounts)
https://github.com/mjhea0/passport-examples

Good luck!